# Compiling meep with openmpi

Tags: macos, compilation, osx-snow-leopard, openmpi, meep

I am trying to build [meep](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep) from MIT with OpenMPI on an iMac with Corei7 processor. I installed OpenMPI using macport.

I have also installed hdf5 with OpenMPI.

Now when I try to compile meep with mpi using `--with-mpi`, meep does not compile and gives the following error message.

```
CXXLD  meep_mpi
Undefined symbols:
  "MPI::Comm::Set_errhandler(MPI::Errhandler const&)", referenced from:
  vtable for MPI::Intercommin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Graphcommin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Cartcommin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Intracommin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Commin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Intercommin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
  vtable for MPI::Graphcommin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
  vtable for MPI::Cartcommin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
  vtable for MPI::Intracommin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
  vtable for MPI::Commin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
  "MPI::Win::Set_errhandler(MPI::Errhandler const&)", referenced from:
  vtable for MPI::Winin libmeep_mpi.a(h5file.o)
  vtable for MPI::Winin libmeep_mpi.a(mympi.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [meep_mpi] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do not understand whats going wrong. I am following the instructions given in the meep website. [Parallel Meep](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Parallel_Meep) and [Meep Installation](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep_Installation#MPI_.28parallel_machines.29)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend mpich vs. openmpi (my preference), but make sure your HDF5 MPI install is okay (i.e., make sure you set the --with-mpi configure flag and check that your config has found your mpi install in the final message after running configure).

Comment: I installed HDF5 using using openmpi option in MacPort. I thought it will install a parallel version of HDF5. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Definitely! You have to pre-install the relevant dev libraries of the MPI of your choice prior to building HDF5. Per my insistence on checking that your MPI install was found during the ./configure step of the HDF5 install.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It works if you link the openmpi binaries to mpixxx equivalents (like openmpicc -> mpicc). Otherwise the configuration script is looking for them but cannot find them and discards the --with-mpi flag.